# VMware ESXi 3.5 HP Proliant DL380 G4 reduce fan noise

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, hp-proliant

I've set up VMware ESXi v3.5 on an HP Proliant DL380 G4, and I'd like a way to reduce the fan noise.

Under Health status, I see the following:
[image: ESXi screenshot]

Is this normal? I've read about there being a Fan component as well.

Is there a firmware/BIOS update that would help?

I've found `HP Management Agents for VMware ESX Server 3.x` on the HP website, but it appears to not work for ESXi.

Do I have to buy ESX? (Where/how/$?) If I enable ssh, can I install the agent? How?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because fans are loud in servers. It should be in a server room with proper environmental controls and the noise shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MDMarra It's probably not good for fans to be running 24/7 at 100% capacity - I'd like some way to be able to monitor/control them.

Comment: Why isn't that good? Unlike desktops, servers are specc'd for 24x7 continuous operation. I'd be wary of manually touching anything related to fan speed on a server.

Comment: @MDMarra I thought that they should be controlled by the HP Agents, not just on 100% all the time. (And that it isn't great for their life span, if the temperature is OK then they can run at 10% instead?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have any options for *ESXi 3.5*. The fan control on that model is managed via the HP Management Agents, but those are not available for ESXi 3.5.

ESXi versions 4 and 5 have agents available as add-ons or with HP's specific ESXi builds.

It's an old server, though. If this is a new installation, please use one of the current builds of VMWare. ESXi 4 will work on that machine.

Comment: VMware did make an HP-specific build of ESXi 3.5 available at one time (3.5U2, I believe), but it's no longer available for download.

Comment: Right, but there's no reason to use 3.5 (versus 4.x) it if this is a new install. I'm assuming it's a new install because the surprise at the fan speed/noise.

Comment: Agreed on both counts. If ESXi 4 runs on a G4-class system, there's no reason to stick with 3.5.

Comment: The VMWare compatibility list says that `3.5 U5` is the latest compatible release. I'd also like the use ESX on a DL360 G4p, and I'd like to keep my versions consistent. Why do you think it will work?

Comment: 4.1 works on G4 systems.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot. Cheers!